# Lightweight AP won't join with Wireless Lan Controller

Tags: cisco, wireless, access-point, cisco-wlc

I'm trying to set up a wireless network, and learn at the same time.
I'm using a Cisco 5508 WLC and a AIR-CAP3702I-A-K9 lightweight AP.
The problem I'm having is that the LAP won't joing with the WLC.  I have no switched or routers in between, only the 5508 WLC, and the AP plugged into the Ciscp PoE adapter.
I have in internal DHCP server set up on the WLC, with the scope beint 172.16.16.100 - 172.16.16.200.
The management interface is assigned  172.16.16.10/24 and bound to distribution port.
The LAP is getting assigned an address ( see output ) which is in the correct subnet, but it never joins the controler.  In fact it seems to give up after a while and request a new address from DHCP, so it keeps starting the process over with a higher IP address.

The output from : ***#debug capwap client event*** is also below.
The only thing useful I can see is that it's sending a Discovery Request, but then reports

> Failed to send packet to destination FF01::18C

also

> Could not discover any MWAR

I don't know what MWAR means.
WLC > show sysinfo

```
Product Version.................................. 7.0.252.0
Bootloader Version............................... 1.0.1
Field Recovery Image Version..................... 6.0.182.0
```

AP #show version

```
Cisco IOS Software, C3700 Software (AP3G2-K9W8-M), Version 15.3(3)JA9, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2016 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Fri 27-May-16 02:08 by prod_rel_team

ROM: Bootstrap program is C3700 boot loader
BOOTLDR: C3700 Boot Loader (AP3G2-BOOT-M) LoaderVersion 15.2(4)JB, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

AP84b8.0255.9bcc uptime is 21 minutes
System returned to ROM by power-on
System image file is "flash:/ap3g2-k9w8-mx.153-3.JA9/ap3g2-k9w8-xx.153-3.JA9"
Last reload reason:
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
BVI1                       172.16.16.130   YES DHCP   up                    up
Dot11Radio0                unassigned      NO  unset  up                    up
Dot11Radio1                unassigned      NO  unset  up                    up
GigabitEthernet0           unassigned      NO  unset  up                    up
Virtual-WLAN0              unassigned      NO  unset  up                    up
Virtual-WLAN0.1            unassigned      NO  unset  up                    up



*Mar  1 00:26:59.015: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway  - gateway found 172.16.16.10
Not in Bound state.
*Mar  1 00:27:04.015: %CAPWAP-3-DHCP_RENEW: Could not discover WLC. Either IP address is not assigned or assigned IP is wrong. Renewing DHCP IP.
*Mar  1 00:27:04.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Discovery failed 5 times. Release/Renew DHCP
*Mar  1 00:27:04.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway  - gateway NOT found
*Mar  1 00:27:04.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Discovery Request sent to 255.255.255.255 with discovery type set to 0
*Mar  1 00:27:04.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Send broadcast discovery request
*Mar  1 00:27:04.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Failed to send packet to destination FF01::18C
*Mar  1 00:27:04.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Discovery Request sent to FF01::18C with discovery type set to 0
*Mar  1 00:27:07.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: ADDING IP 172.16.16.131, 255.255.255.0 resolvemethod  A, ip_dhcp_addr 1
*Mar  1 00:27:07.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Teardown DTLS connection local port 22974
*Mar  1 00:27:07.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG:
 Engine id is set to -1408233341

*Mar  1 00:27:07.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: ip_address_change: DCB updated: type-1, address-AC101083

*Mar  1 00:27:07.019: CAPWAP_DETAIL: Dtls Event = 40 Capwap State = 2.
*Mar  1 00:27:07.091: %DHCP-6-ADDRESS_ASSIGN: Interface BVI1 assigned DHCP address 172.16.16.131, mask 255.255.255.0, hostname AP84b8.0255.9bcc

*Mar  1 00:27:07.091: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: ADDING IP 172.16.16.131, 255.255.255.0 resolvemethod  A, ip_dhcp_addr 1
*Mar  1 00:27:07.091: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG:
 Engine id is set to -1408233341

*Mar  1 00:27:07.091: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: ip_address_change: DCB updated: type-1, address-AC101083

Translating "CISCO-CAPWAP-CONTROLLER.monkey.net"...domain server (172.16.16.1)
*Mar  1 00:27:14.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Could not discover any MWAR.
*Mar  1 00:27:14.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Starting Discovery. Initializing discovery latency in discovery responses.
*Mar  1 00:27:14.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: CAPWAP State: Discovery.
*Mar  1 00:27:14.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway - Adding default route for gateway 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:27:15.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway  - gateway found 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:27:15.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway - Adding default route for gateway 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:27:15.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway  - gateway found 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:27:15.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: DNS Option IpAddr 172.16.16.1 SwitchName CISCO-CAPWAP-CONTROLLER.monkey.net config
CAPWAP Client config display debugging is on
AP84b8.0255.9bcc#
AP84b8.0255.9bcc#vvvv

*Mar  1 00:28:27.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Send IPv4 Broadcast discovery request

*Mar  1 00:28:37.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Could not discover any MWAR.
*Mar  1 00:28:37.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Starting Discovery. Initializing discovery latency in discovery responses.
*Mar  1 00:28:37.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: CAPWAP State: Discovery.
*Mar  1 00:28:37.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway - Adding default route for gateway 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:28:37.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway  - gateway found 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:28:37.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway - Adding default route for gateway 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:28:37.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway  - gateway found 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:28:37.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Discovery Request sent to 255.255.255.255 with discovery type set to 0
*Mar  1 00:28:37.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Send broadcast discovery request
*Mar  1 00:28:37.019: CAPWAP_DETAIL: Vendor specific payload validated.
*Mar  1 00:28:37.019: CAPWAP_DETAIL: Vendor specific payload validated.
*Mar  1 00:28:37.019: CAPWAP_DETAIL: Vendor specific payload validated.
*Mar  1 00:28:37.019: CAPWAP_DETAIL: Vendor specific payload validated.
*Mar  1 00:28:37.019: CAPWAP_DETAIL: Vendor specific payload validated.
*Mar  1 00:28:37.019: CAPWAP_DETAIL: Vendor specific payload validated.
*Mar  1 00:28:47.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Could not discover any MWAR.
*Mar  1 00:28:47.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Starting Discovery. Initializing discovery latency in discovery responses.
*Mar  1 00:28:47.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: CAPWAP State: Discovery.
*Mar  1 00:28:47.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway - Adding default route for gateway 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:28:47.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway  - gateway found 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:28:47.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway - Adding default route for gateway 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:28:47.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway  - gateway found 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:28:47.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Send IPv4 Broadcast discovery request

*Mar  1 00:28:57.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Could not discover any MWAR.
*Mar  1 00:28:57.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Starting Discovery. Initializing discovery latency in discovery responses.
*Mar  1 00:28:57.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: CAPWAP State: Discovery.
*Mar  1 00:28:57.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway - Adding default route for gateway 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:28:57.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway  - gateway found 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:28:57.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway - Adding default route for gateway 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:28:57.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway  - gateway found 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:28:57.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Discovery Request sent to 255.255.255.255 with discovery type set to 0
*Mar  1 00:28:57.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Send broadcast discovery request
*Mar  1 00:28:57.019: CAPWAP_DETAIL: Vendor specific payload validated.
*Mar  1 00:28:57.019: CAPWAP_DETAIL: Vendor specific payload validated.
*Mar  1 00:28:57.019: CAPWAP_DETAIL: Vendor specific payload validated.
*Mar  1 00:28:57.019: CAPWAP_DETAIL: Vendor specific payload validated.
*Mar  1 00:28:57.019: CAPWAP_DETAIL: Vendor specific payload validated.
*Mar  1 00:28:57.019: CAPWAP_DETAIL: Vendor specific payload validated.
*Mar  1 00:29:07.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Could not discover any MWAR.
*Mar  1 00:29:07.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Starting Discovery. Initializing discovery latency in discovery responses.
*Mar  1 00:29:07.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: CAPWAP State: Discovery.
*Mar  1 00:29:07.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway - Adding default route for gateway 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:29:07.019: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway  - gateway found 172.16.16.10
Not in Bound state.
*Mar  1 00:29:12.019: %CAPWAP-3-DHCP_RENEW: Could not discover WLC. Either IP address is not assigned or assigned IP is wrong. Renewing DHCP IP.
*Mar  1 00:29:12.023: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Discovery failed 5 times. Release/Renew DHCP
*Mar  1 00:29:12.023: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway  - gateway NOT found
*Mar  1 00:29:12.023: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Send IPv4 Broadcast discovery request

*Mar  1 00:29:15.023: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: ADDING IP 172.16.16.132, 255.255.255.0 resolvemethod  A, ip_dhcp_addr 1
*Mar  1 00:29:15.023: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Teardown DTLS connection local port 22974
*Mar  1 00:29:15.023: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG:
 Engine id is set to -1408233340

*Mar  1 00:29:15.023: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: ip_address_change: DCB updated: type-1, address-AC101084

*Mar  1 00:29:15.023: CAPWAP_DETAIL: Dtls Event = 40 Capwap State = 2.
*Mar  1 00:29:15.095: %DHCP-6-ADDRESS_ASSIGN: Interface BVI1 assigned DHCP address 172.16.16.132, mask 255.255.255.0, hostname AP84b8.0255.9bcc

*Mar  1 00:29:15.095: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: ADDING IP 172.16.16.132, 255.255.255.0 resolvemethod  A, ip_dhcp_addr 1
*Mar  1 00:29:15.095: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG:
 Engine id is set to -1408233340

*Mar  1 00:29:15.095: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: ip_address_change: DCB updated: type-1, address-AC101084

Translating "CISCO-CAPWAP-CONTROLLER.monkey.net"...domain server (172.16.16.1)
*Mar  1 00:29:22.023: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Could not discover any MWAR.
*Mar  1 00:29:22.023: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: Starting Discovery. Initializing discovery latency in discovery responses.
*Mar  1 00:29:22.023: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: CAPWAP State: Discovery.
*Mar  1 00:29:22.023: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway - Adding default route for gateway 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:29:23.023: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway  - gateway found 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:29:23.023: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway - Adding default route for gateway 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:29:23.023: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: spamResolveStaticGateway  - gateway found 172.16.16.10
*Mar  1 00:29:23.023: %CAPWAP-3-EVENTLOG: DNS Option IpAddr 172.16.16.1 SwitchName CISCO-CAPWAP-CONTROLLER.monkey.net
```

WLC debugs

```
(Cisco Controller) >debug capwap events

Incorrect input! Use 'debug capwap [events/errors/info/detail] [enable/disable]

(Cisco Controller) >debug capwap events enable

(Cisco Controller) >debug capwap errors enable

(Cisco Controller) >debug capwap detail enable

(Cisco Controller) >debug capwap info enable

(Cisco Controller) >debug capwap packet enable

 Warning! Enabling this debug with large number of AP's connected, May flood console with message logs !!!.
 Are you sure you want to continue? (y/N)*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:55:9b:cc CAPWAP Control Msg Received from 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 length = 4, packet received from 84:b8:2:69:7f:20

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 packet received of length 189 from 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Msg Type = 1 Capwap state = 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery Request from 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery request: Total msgEleLen = 165

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 1 msgEleType = 20

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery Type = Unknown

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 160

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 62 msgEleType = 38

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 94

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 40 msgEleType = 39

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 50

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 1 msgEleType = 41

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 45

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 1 msgEleType = 44

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 40

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 10 msgEleType = 37

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Vendor specific payload from AP  84:B8:02:69:7F:20 validated

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery request: Vendor payload type = 207, length = 10

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 26

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 22 msgEleType = 37

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Vendor specific payload from AP  84:B8:02:69:7F:20 validated

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery request: Vendor payload type = 5, length = 22

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.517: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Join Priority Processing status = 0, Incoming Ap's Priority 1, MaxLrads = 50, joined Aps =0
*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 1. 0 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 2. 232 3

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 3. 0 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 4. 50 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgLength = 36

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: AC Descriptor message element len = 40

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 acName = monkey_house

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp:AC Name message element length = 56

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: WTP Radio Information msg length = 65

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: CAPWAP Control IPV4 Address len = 75

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: CAPWAP Control IPV6 Address len = 97

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: Mwar type payload len = 108

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: Expire MIC type payload len = 122

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: Time sync payload len = 137

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 encodeLen = 137 len = 16

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery Response sent to 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery Response sent to 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 WTP already released
*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:55:9b:cc CAPWAP Control Msg Received from 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 length = 4, packet received from 84:b8:2:69:7f:20

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 packet received of length 189 from 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Msg Type = 1 Capwap state = 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery Request from 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery request: Total msgEleLen = 165

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 1 msgEleType = 20

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery Type = Unknown

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 160

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 62 msgEleType = 38

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 94

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 40 msgEleType = 39

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 50

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 1 msgEleType = 41

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 45

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 1 msgEleType = 44

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 40

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 10 msgEleType = 37

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Vendor specific payload from AP  84:B8:02:69:7F:20 validated

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery request: Vendor payload type = 207, length = 10

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 26

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 22 msgEleType = 37

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Vendor specific payload from AP  84:B8:02:69:7F:20 validated

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery request: Vendor payload type = 5, length = 22

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Join Priority Processing status = 0, Incoming Ap's Priority 1, MaxLrads = 50, joined Aps =0
*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 1. 0 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 2. 232 3

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 3. 0 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 4. 50 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgLength = 36

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: AC Descriptor message element len = 40

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 acName = monkey_house

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp:AC Name message element length = 56

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: WTP Radio Information msg length = 65

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: CAPWAP Control IPV4 Address len = 75

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: CAPWAP Control IPV6 Address len = 97

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: Mwar type payload len = 108

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: Expire MIC type payload len = 122

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: Time sync payload len = 137

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 encodeLen = 137 len = 16

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery Response sent to 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery Response sent to 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:39.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 WTP already released
*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:55:9b:cc CAPWAP Control Msg Received from 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 length = 4, packet received from 84:b8:2:69:7f:20

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 packet received of length 189 from 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Msg Type = 1 Capwap state = 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery Request from 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery request: Total msgEleLen = 165

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 1 msgEleType = 20

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery Type = Unknown

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 160

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 62 msgEleType = 38

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 94

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 40 msgEleType = 39

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 50

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 1 msgEleType = 41

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 45

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 1 msgEleType = 44

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 40

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 10 msgEleType = 37

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Vendor specific payload from AP  84:B8:02:69:7F:20 validated

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery request: Vendor payload type = 207, length = 10

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 26

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 22 msgEleType = 37

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Vendor specific payload from AP  84:B8:02:69:7F:20 validated

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery request: Vendor payload type = 5, length = 22

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Join Priority Processing status = 0, Incoming Ap's Priority 1, MaxLrads = 50, joined Aps =0
*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 1. 0 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 2. 232 3

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 3. 0 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 4. 50 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgLength = 36

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: AC Descriptor message element len = 40

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.518: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 acName = monkey_house

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp:AC Name message element length = 56

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: WTP Radio Information msg length = 65

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: CAPWAP Control IPV4 Address len = 75

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: CAPWAP Control IPV6 Address len = 97

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: Mwar type payload len = 108

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: Expire MIC type payload len = 122

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: Time sync payload len = 137

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 encodeLen = 137 len = 16

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery Response sent to 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery Response sent to 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 WTP already released
*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:55:9b:cc CAPWAP Control Msg Received from 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 length = 4, packet received from 84:b8:2:69:7f:20

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 packet received of length 189 from 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Msg Type = 1 Capwap state = 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery Request from 172.16.16.134:22974

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery request: Total msgEleLen = 165

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 1 msgEleType = 20

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery Type = Unknown

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 160

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 62 msgEleType = 38

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 94

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 40 msgEleType = 39

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 50

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 1 msgEleType = 41

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 45

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 1 msgEleType = 44

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 40

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.519: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 10 msgEleType = 37

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Vendor specific payload from AP  84:B8:02:69:7F:20 validated

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery request: Vendor payload type = 207, length = 10

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 26

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgEleLength = 22 msgEleType = 37

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Vendor specific payload from AP  84:B8:02:69:7F:20 validated

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery request: Vendor payload type = 5, length = 22

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Total msgEleLen = 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Join Priority Processing status = 0, Incoming Ap's Priority 1, MaxLrads = 50, joined Aps =0
*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 1. 0 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 2. 232 3

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 3. 0 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 4. 50 0

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 msgLength = 36

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: AC Descriptor message element len = 40

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 acName = monkey_house

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp:AC Name message element length = 56

*spamApTask4: Jan 26 10:49:59.520: 84:b8:02:69:7f:20 Discovery resp: WTP Radio Information msg length = 65
```

Comment: What is the WLC software version?

Comment: Also, what is the software version of the AP itself?

Comment: It appears that DHCP sets the gateway to 172.16.16.1 but it doesn’t exist.  Either create it or remove it from the scope.

Comment: As an addition to user56700's requests, what do you see on debugs on the controller when the AP is trying to join? You also might try enabling more debugs on the AP to get additional messaging why it can't use the controller it found.

Comment: @user56700 I've added the "show version" and "show sysinfo" outputs to the main questions.

Comment: @RonTrunk   There's no router yet, just the AP and WLC.  I made change to the dhcp config  in the WLC to set the gateway ip to 172.16.16.10, which is the management interface itself.  Now I'm not getting that error, but the AP is stil not joining

Comment: @YLearn  I've added a WLC debug output, and also added debuging on the AP for clent events, detail, and errors.  Hope that helps.

Comment: By the way, what is an MWAR ??  That seems to be a relevent message I'm getting.  Also what does a WTP refer to?

Comment: Comments are not for asking additional questions. If you have additional questions, you should use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The software version that you are running on your WLC is not compatible with the 3700 series access points. You need to upgrade your code to at least 7.6.100.0 which is what Cisco indicates is the first version of code to support that AP platform.

You can find the compatibility matrix from Cisco [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/compatibility/matrix/compatibility-matrix.html).

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the problem.  I would have expected some sort of "incompatible WCL" notification in the AP debug or vice versa though.  Thanks.